# Electron IPC behaving inconsistently

Tags: electron

I have ipc connected and sending messages early, but when I call ipc later in onclick it is failing.

I am using ipc because I want to communicate with the file system for some settings.  It works fine here in Main:

```
ipcMain.on("settings", (event, arg) => {
      console.log("Writing muting to settings: " + arg.settings)
      switch(arg.settings){
        case "mute_status":
          event.reply("settings_reply", settings.muted)
          break;
        case "mute:true":
          event.reply("settings_reply", "muted set to true")
        default:
          event.reply('settings_reply', 'Sure thing, got it')
      }
    })
```

Renderer:

```
ipc.sendSync('settings',{"settings": "mute_status"})
ipc.once('settings_reply', (event, arg) => {
    console.log('Muted is: ' + arg)
    if(arg){    
        place_icon("mute", "volume_div")
        document.getElementById("audio").muted = true
    } else {
        place_icon("volume-up", "volume_div")
    }
})
```

When I later make another call it works sometimes(almost always if I restart Windows).  It either works or doesn't with each run of the program.  The second call connects to the same in main.js with this in the renderer:

```
ipc.sendSync("settings", {"settings": "mute:" + muted})
    
ipc.once('settings_reply', (event, arg) => {
 console.log("We're talking")
} )
```

I've tried quite a few things and I'm happy to provide more info if needed.  What is causing this?  How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You are using [ipcRenderer.once(channel, listener)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendereroncechannel-listener). Its purpose is to register a one-time event handler which will be removed after it is triggered. Change it to `ipcRenderer.on(channel, listener)`

> **ipcRenderer.once**(channel, listener)
>
> ```
> • channel String
> • listener Function
>     event IpcRendererEvent
>     ...args any[]
> ```
>
> Adds a one time listener function for the event. This listener is
> invoked only the next time a message is sent to channel, after which
> it is removed.

Comment: That was I defined 'once' again later with the second call.  Regardless, changing it to 'on' does not improve the behavior.  I also removed the second call to once, but it still behaves erratically.  I have also tried separating these calls into different channels.  It still works occasionally, but definitely not reliably.  I do appreciate your input, though.